# How to skip this countdown using Violentmonkey script

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make a greasemonkey script to skip this countdown? I've already tried to make a script by myself but I'm very newbie at javascript so I couldn't figure out a way to that.

Here's the code of the countdown (it is an inline script, and it is the only inline script in that page).

MY CODE

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Site Countdown Skip
// @autor SecretX
// @namespace namespace_secretx
// @description Skip the silly countdown.
// @version 2019.06.23
// @match http://example.com/download/?*
// @match https:/example.com/download/?*
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==

var changed = 0;

window.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', function(e) {

    if(e.target===document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    window.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee, true);
}, true);
```

PAGE CODE

```
<div id="pleasewait">Please wait <span id="contador">15</span> seconds</div>
<iframe class="clearfix" src="https://a.site.com.br/download/php_code.php" id="iframe" style="border: 0;width:100%;height:100%;" __idm_frm__="12884901909"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var seconds;
  var temp;

  function countdown() {
    seconds = document.getElementById('countdown1').innerHTML;
    seconds = parseInt(seconds, 10);

    if (seconds == 1) {
      temp = document.getElementById('pleasewait');
      temp.innerHTML = '<a href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:00et8wt78wga5tre874fe8afw8w&amp;dn=Video_File_999_FHD.mkv&amp;xl=687980321&amp;tr=udp://tracker.tracker.org:1337/announce" id="continuar"><i id="cola"></i></a>';
      return;
    }

    seconds--;
    temp = document.getElementById('countdown1');
    temp.innerHTML = seconds;
    timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
  } 

  countdown();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you already made an attempt at making this work? if so can you include your code to the question so we can try and help?

Comment: Also, what is it that you are trying to do exactly with this code and countdown?

Comment: This is my code atm, it's not much & it's not working. I just want to skip the countdown, I mean, I want to access the site and have the link instantly instead of having to wait 15 seconds.

Comment: Is the first block of code your own and the second is the function you are trying to override? Or am i not understanding and they are both your own, in which case i am not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: @K.D it should be clear now. First code is mine and second is the page code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, if you want to skip the count down as much as you can without editing the HTML or JS in your second block of code, then you can just add this line of JS to your document:

`document.getElementById('countdown1').innerHTML = 1;`

This will set the elements `innerHtml` to 1.
In the JS function `countdown()`, there is an if statement that is checking if the `innerHtml` of the "countdown1" element is 1, and if so then it updates the "temp" elements contents.

Here is an example:

```html
<div id="pleasewait">Please wait <span id="countdown1">15</span> seconds</div>
<iframe class="clearfix" src="https://a.site.com.br/download/php_code.php" id="iframe" style="border: 0;width:100%;height:100%;" __idm_frm__="12884901909"></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById('countdown1').innerHTML = 1
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var seconds;
  var temp;

  function countdown() {
    seconds = document.getElementById('countdown1').innerHTML;
    seconds = parseInt(seconds, 10);

    if (seconds == 1) {
      temp = document.getElementById('pleasewait');
      temp.innerHTML = 'LOAD THIS';
      return;
    }

    seconds--;
    temp = document.getElementById('countdown1');
    temp.innerHTML = seconds;
    timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
  } 

  countdown();
</script>
```

I wrote `LOAD THIS` instead of what was there originally just for the example, all you really need to do is to put this line:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('countdown1').innerHTML = 1
</script>
```

After this element:

```
<div id="pleasewait">Please wait <span id="countdown1">15</span> seconds</div>
```

Comment: It works, but is there a way to replace some of the javascript already included in the page to rip the countdown part and just load the link on the "pleasewait" object?

Comment: If you know what the output of the function is going to be then you could just recreate the function and change it to skip the countdown.